# Можно ли выгружать Json в несколько разных блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Всем добрый вечер.
столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю как ее решить, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.
есть некий Json файлик, который я вывожу вот таким вот образом.

```
var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out += '<div class="goods">';

        out += `<img class="goods_img" src="${data[key].image}">`;

        out += `<p class="show_goods-category">${data[key].category}</p>`;
        out += '</div>';
    }
    $('#goods').html(out);    //вывод  информации в ('#goods')
```

на выходе получается вот такая картина.

```
<div id="goods">
'<div class="goods">

<img class="goods_img" src="images/apple.png">
<p class="goods-category">Акция</p>

</div>

'<div class="goods">

<img class="goods_img" src="images/tomato.png">
<p class="goods-category">в наличии</p>

</div>

'<div class="goods">

<img class="goods_img" src="images/strawberry.png">
<p class="goods-category">под заказ</p>

</div>
</div>
```

и все выгружается в один блок ('#goods'). но это не совсем то что нужно

можно ли сделать что бы

```
все блоки у которых $('.goods-category') == "Акция" выгружались в контейнер с классом $('.stock-goods');
все блоки у которых $('.goods-category') == "в наличии" выгружались в контейнер с классом $('.in-stock-goods');
все блоки у которых $('.goods-category') == "под заказ" выгружались в контейнер с классом $('.order-goods');
```

буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: в чем проблема то? очевидно, надо неким образом задать соответствие имени категории и места назначения для начала. а в цикле каждый блок добавлять отдельно, а не клепать портянку

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать так:

```
var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out = '<div class="goods">';

        out += `<img class="goods_img" src="${data[key].image}">`;

        out += `<p class="show_goods-category">${data[key].category}</p>`;
        out += '</div>';

      // 1 варинт = тут через if выгружаете куда нужно
      if(data[key].category == 'action')
        $('.stock-goods').html(out); 
      if(data[key].category == 'order')
        $('.order-goods').html(out); 


      // 2 вариант формирует сразу класс
      $('.' + data[key].category '-goods').html(out);
    }
```

суть надеюсь понятна, в каждом цикле обновляете формируемый блок, и в конце итерации добавляете куда нужно.